# Obtaining all the methods in a class --- error prone

Tags: java, reflection, classnotfoundexception

I am new to reflection and to practice, I downloaded a random Java project from a website. I decided to find out which class has the main method so I wrote the following code:

```
package reflection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class FindMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        if(args.length==0){
            System.out.println("Exiting");
            System.exit(1);
        }else{
            Path p = Paths.get(args[0]);
            DirectoryStream<Path> allClassFiles = Files.newDirectoryStream(p, "*.class");
            for(Path each : allClassFiles){
//              System.out.println(each.getFileName());
                try {
                    findMethods(each.getFileName().toString());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void findMethods(String file) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        System.out.println(file);
        Class c = Class.forName(file);
        Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method each : m){
            System.out.println(each.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

`System.out.println(each.getFileName());` properly returns the `.class` files in the folder however, **it is interspersed with stack trace of ClassNotFoundException**

The classes are as follows:

```
Addwindow$1.class
Addwindow$2.class
Addwindow.class
Authorwindow.class
clsConnection.class
clsSettings$1.class
clsSettings.class
Deletewindow$1.class
Deletewindow$2.class
Deletewindow.class
Editwindow$1.class
Editwindow$2.class
Editwindow.class
Emprptwindow$PrintCommand.class
Emprptwindow.class
Helpwindow.class
LoginFrame$1.class
LoginFrame.class
MainMenu$1.class
MainMenu$2.class
MainMenu.class
Payrptwindow.class
printwindow$1.class
printwindow.class
Settingswindow$1.class
Settingswindow.class
```

What changes do I need to make to the code to get the methods from each class ?

### Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Settingswindow
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at reflection.FindMethods.findMethods(FindMethods.java:33)
    at reflection.FindMethods.main(FindMethods.java:22)
```

### Random project being talked about:

http://projectseminar.org/java-projects/payroll-accounting-system/98/

Comment: Did you set up the classpath correctly? Are those classes in a package? (Hint: they almost certainly are if they're part of a public project) Remember, you need to use the fully qualified binary class names.

Comment: @Antimony They arent in a pakage!

Comment: What is this Java project? It's a very strange project that doesn't use packages.

Comment: @Antimony payroll system. Everything is dumped in default package

Comment: That's not good practice, and you'll want to move the classes outside of the default package.

Comment: One other thing, if you actually want to determine the intended entry point to the application, it's best to start by checking the manifest file. That tells you which class's main method is executed when the jar is run.

Answer (score 1):

`.class` is part of the filename, but it isn't part of the class name. You need to strip it before passing it to `Class.forName`.

Another issue is that `forName` expects packages to be separated using periods, rather than than slashes or whatever directory separator your filesystem uses. If everything is in the default package, this shouldn't be an issue though.

If it's still not working, you should double check the classpath.

Comment: Maybe I need a workaround. Like using a `BufferedReader`, reading line by line and if the line contains `public static void main` then viola!!

Comment: Could you post one of the actual stacktraces please? It's hard to tell what the problem might be without more information. Also post a link to the actual project you're using if possible.

Comment: It's getting late now. I'll check them tomorrow if you still haven't solved the problem

Comment: Basically, I am attempting to run the project, see what it is and learn from it... I cannot get it to run, so far. Help appreciated :)

Comment: @Little, did you double check your classpath? I'm able to run it just fine. Also, do you realize the source code is provided, right?

Comment: Yes, I did! I tried `java main` to run the `main` class and I get an error that could not find or load main class. Also, there are few other errors when I try to run it in Eclipse!!!

Comment: Try running LoginFrame. I believe that's the main class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26811/discussion-between-little-child-and-antimony)

Answer (score 0):

Class names that contain a `$` are anonymous classes within the outer class (determined by the name to the left of the `$`). You can safely ignore those in your search for `main`. Just test for the presence of a `$` in the class names in your main loop and skip the processing.

Without knowing more about what app you are looking at, I can't say why your code can't find some of the other classes (like `clsConnection`).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in this approach - you load all project's classes. It is better to analize classes without loading them. There are tools for that. Here's what we can do with http://www.jboss.org/javassist

```
public static void findMethods(String file) throws Exception {
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        CtClass cc = cp.makeClass(is);
        for (CtMethod m : cc.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }
}
```